# Python function to get numbers around another number

Tags: python, interval

I made a function to get a list with numbers around another number. Example: I want to get in a range of 2 numbers around 4. This will return: `[2, 6]`. You can set a min number and a max_number. That means when I set a min_num, the lower number should not be lower than the min number.

```
import sys


def get_numbers_around(number: int, min_num: int = None, max_num: int = None, _range: int = 2, on_fail_no_error: bool = False) -> range:
    if max_num is None:
        max_num = sys.maxsize

    if min_num is None:
        min_num = -sys.maxsize - 1

    diff = max_num - min_num
    if diff < _range:
        if not on_fail_no_error:
            raise ValueError(
                "Range is too small. Range is {0} big but difference between max_num and min_num is {1} big! ({0} < {1}".format(
                    range, max_num - min_num))
        else:
            return range(number - diff, number + diff)

    final_list = [number - _range, number + _range]

    if final_list[0] < min_num:
        diff = abs(min_num - final_list[0])
        final_list[0] = min_num
        final_list[1] += diff

    if final_list[1] > max_num:
        diff = abs(final_list[1] - max_num)
        final_list[1] = max_num
        final_list[0] -= diff

    return range(final_list[0], final_list[1])


print(get_numbers_around(4)) # range(2, 6)
print(get_numbers_around(4, _range=5)) # range(-1, 9)
print(get_numbers_around(0, min_num=0, max_num=1, _range=4, on_fail_no_error=True)) # range(-1, 1)
print(get_numbers_around(0, min_num=0, max_num=1, _range=4)) # ValueError
```

I think it is possible to optimize this code but I don't know how. Does anoyne have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your code seems really complicated, and so you should follow KISS and YAGNI.
- `max_num` and `min_num` don't work the way I would expect them to.
- The error goes against what I think is Pythonic. Just return the smaller set.

```
def get_numbers_around(number, size):
    return range(number - size, number + size)
```

If you then need to implement `min_num` and `max_num` create a filter:

```
def filter_between(values, minimum=float('-inf'), maximum=float('inf')):
    return (v for v in values if minimum <= v <= maximum)
```

---

```
>>> get_numbers_around(4, 5)
range(-1, 9)
>>> list(filter_between(_, 0))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: This interface is much more pythonic. But there is some utility in returning a `range` object; in particular, iterating through a generator should be faster without checking that each values is in range. Why not just return `range(max(values.start, minimum), min(values.stop, maximum))`.

Comment: @BenjaminKuykendall I don't know how the code is being used. The person seems to like over-complicating things, and needs YAGNI and KISS in their life. Yes you could do it that way, but I still think YAGNI.

Comment: But with this method there will be missing some numbers. Example: I have the number 1 and I want 2 numbers around. Then I'll get `[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]` (I have 5 numbers now) . When I filter this, I'll get `[0, 1, 2]` (Now I only have 3 numbers but this should be 5.). The list should be like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] `.

Comment: @Myzel394 Yours doesn't do this either. You can even see it in your examples above. `range` doesn't include the last value, like you think it does.